# When playing on a grid, can I pour a flask of oil on any adjacent square or just on the one I am standing on?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, battle-map

The description of a flask of oil says:

> You can also pour a flask of oil on the ground to cover a 5-foot-square area, provided that the surface is level.

When playing on a grid, can I pour a flask of oil on any adjacent square or just on the one I am standing on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### You can pour the oil on adjacent squares.

This is not spelled out very clearly, but your **reach** is assumed to be 5 feet unless specified otherwise. In the section on [melee attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks), it is stated:

> Most creatures have a 5-foot **reach** and can thus attack targets within 5 feet of them when making a melee attack. Certain creatures (typically those larger than Medium) have melee attacks with a greater reach than 5 feet, as noted in their descriptions.

Again, this is in the section on melee attacks, which may not appear to be entirely relevant. But the next paragraph has further guidance, concerning **unarmed strikes**:

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons).

So while it nowhere says I can pour my oil on an adjacent square, I can headbutt or punch enemies in adjacent squares, so it is quite natural that I can also pour a flask of oil into an adjacent square.

Comment: @Rykara Although the OP's question is about poured oil, you don't need to invoke Rule 0 for thrown oil.  "Oil usually comes in a clay flask that holds 1 pint. As an action, you can splash the oil in this flask onto a creature within 5 feet of you or throw it up to 20 feet, shattering it on impact. Make a ranged Attack against a target creature **or object**, treating the oil as an Improvised Weapon."  The 'object' in this case would be a specified section of floor.